# Decompile MS Project VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project

Is there a way to decompile MS Project VBA in either the .mpt file or the project? I know with Access you can open the file with a decompile argument.

Comment: VBA is not compiled -- that is, the VBA source code is stored inside the .mpt file. What happens when you open the .mpt file with Project?

Comment: Is it password protected? If not, just open the mpt file, and select "Visual Basic".

Comment: Decompiling can enable recovery of corrupted VBA. I decompile Access code frequently and always before compiling before distribution. I was simply wondering if there was a way to decompile an MPT file.

Answer (score 0):

Access has a semi-compiled state I think, but Project, Excel, Word and PowerPoint don't.

With Project, be sure to do a File, Save as occasionally as this is the only time  Project does housekeeping on the file to minimise file size.